# why am I getting "actor not found" when calling the last succesful run from an actor in Apify?

Tags: apify

I'm getting this error when calling last succesful run from an Apify actor. Does anybody know why? I couldn't find the actor id anywhere so I used the name of the actor instead.

[image]

this is my api call to get last succesful fun from my actor.....................................

```
func getZillowListings() -> Bool {
        
        //@Binding var listingsResults : Bool
        let token = "SECRET"
        let taskId = "ZE5LuEYvZzcWW0nGA"
        let actorId = "zillow-api-scraper"
        var urlComponents = URLComponents(string: "https://api.apify.com/v2/acts/\(actorId)/runs/last")
        
        urlComponents?.queryItems = [
            URLQueryItem(name: "actorTaskId", value: taskId),
            URLQueryItem(name: "token", value: token),
            URLQueryItem(name: "status", value: "SUCCEEDED"),
        ]
        let url = urlComponents?.url
        
        if let url = url {
            
            // Create URL Request
            var request = URLRequest(url: url, cachePolicy: .reloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 10.0)
            request.httpMethod = "GET"
            //request.addValue("Bearer \(token)", forHTTPHeaderField: "Authorization")
            
            // Get URLSession
            let session = URLSession.shared
            
            // Create Data Task
            let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in
                
                // Check that there isn't an error
                if error == nil {
                    
                    do {
                        
                        if data != nil {
                            
                            let json = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options:[])
                            print("Received response")
                            print(json)
                            
                            
                            // decode the json to an array of listings
                            self.listingsZ = try! JSONDecoder().decode([ListingsZillow].self, from: data!)
                            
                      self.results!.listings.removeAll() {
                            
                            //                            }
                            
                            self.getShortPriceZillow()
                            
                        }
                        
                        
                    }
                    catch {
                        print(error)
                        
                    }
                }
            }
            
            // Start the Data Task
            dataTask.resume()
            return true
        } else {
            return false
        }
        
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For name, you have to use `username~actorname` so `petr_cermak~zillow-api-scraper`. The ID is `x5YtEpoHnmvaaEgoD`